# checking upload file size before uploading to server

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.3

I am trying to upload image using laravel and successfully uploaded 
 images and everything worked fine and I tried to check if validation is working so I tried to upload a mp3 file, at first I get error from laravel.

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

So I googled and I got information that I have to change `post_max_size` in php.ini file.
So I changed to 40 and  my error is gone and I get form validation error file must be image, which is what I expected and then I got a doubt what if someone uploads file greater than 40. So that I am asking this.
How can I set an error message before laravel gives me this

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

I know I can use jquery.prefer (php based) validation. How can I do that? I have seen  example here: http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-l40-csrf-tokenmismatchexception-when-uploading-large-files, but I don't know how to implement it. Please give some advice or where to write code in the above link.

Comment: Could you please obey some of the basic grammar rules that would make reading your question possible? Thanks.

Comment: i edited is this okay

Comment: Well, there is something called "punctuation". It makes sense to use _several_ sentences for a passage exceeing two lines. Not a single sentence spanning over a whole page.

Comment: Think of it like that: it is in _your own interest_ that reading and understanding your question is as easy as possible. Since you want some favor from someone else. Just dumping a whole blob of words and basically expecting everyone else to work through that and try to _guess_ what you might be trying to say is impolite. It is _your_ task to ask in a way that things are readable. This is not unique to StackOverflow, but a general principle of human communication actually.

Comment: i am sorry my English is bad especially grammar

Comment: please give me an answer or any other link